# Retornar apenas álbuns com ao menos uma foto

Tags: facebook

Atualmente estou fazendo a seguinte consulta FQL para retornar todos os albums do usuário logado que possuem ao menos uma foto (com a quantidade de fotos):

```
SELECT object_id, name, photo_count 
FROM album 
WHERE owner = me() AND photo_count > 0
```

Infelizmente a versão 2.1 da plataforma removeu o suporte a FQL.

Sei que posso obter os valores em questão com a seguinte chamada:

```
me/albums?fields=name,id,count
```

Porém não encontrei uma maneira de filtrar álbuns vazios. 
Iterar cada valor e verificar aqueles com `count` diferente de zero não é muito conveniente pois um usuário pode ter uma quantidade grande de albums; eu seria obrigado a iterar sobre várias páginas apenas para contar a quantidade de álbuns não vazios.

---

**Cross posting para o SOen:** [Pergunta em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950367/graph-api-get-only-non-empty-albums)

Comment: Anthony, pelo que vi não tem mesmo como fazer isso, a Graph API é bastante restrita em relação a customização dos resultados... Mas vi que a versão 2.0 terá suporte até agosto de 2016 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog). Precisa mesmo fazer essa migração? Não poderia continuar na versão 2.0 e usando `FQL` apenas para esse propósito, sendo as demais requisições feitas para a versão 2.1?

Comment: Oi Wakim, sim, é uma excelente sugestão. Estou contemplando a possibilidade de permanecer na versão 2.0; a 2.1 quebrou muita coisa para mim. **[Modo aborrecido on]** Parece que cada *upgrade* na plataforma do Facebook introduz meia dúzia de piorias; sem contar as indisponibilidades e *updates* silenciosos que volta e meia quebram algum aspecto da minha aplicação **[Modo aborrecido off]**. Será que eles vão introduzir filtros como esse em uma versão posterior da API ou vamos ficar sem a funcionalidade? :(

Comment: Não faço ideia, cheguei a pesquisar algo mas não achei. Nunca usei o `FQL` diretamente, mas usei apenas um pouco da Graph API pra recuperar e tratar elementos da timeline de um usuário. Acho que eles deveriam fornecer algum "polyfill" pra essa migração, a `FQL` é muito poderosa, já até imagino como vai ser difícil migrar consultas complexas quando eles tirarem do ar... Talvez valha a pena iniciar uma discussão no grupo (caso não haja, ainda não consegui entrar no grupo) https://m.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: @Wakim, pelo visto não tem solução mesmo. Se você quiser transformar seu comentário em uma resposta eu posso aceitá-la. Abraços.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não há nenhuma manipulação possível para esse propósito de filtro ou ordenação de resultados, a *Graph API* é muito rígida nesse aspecto.

Como a versão 2.0, que ainda dá suporte ao *FQL*, [terá suporte até 07/08/2016](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog), minha sugestão é continuar usando o *FQL* para fazer essa e outras consultas mais complexas e migrar os acessos mais simples para a versão 2.1.

Como a *FQL* é infinitamente mais poderosa, em termos de complexidade e da possibilidade de análise de dados, que a *Graph API* somente. Esperamos que o *Facebook* forneça até 2016 uma alternativa que supra a maioria das necessidades, senão poderá causar problemas para muita gente.