# Usar o FQL no facebbok api php 4

Tags: php, facebook

Pessoal preciso executar uma simples FQL usando Facebook SDK PHP 4 uso o seguinte comando:

```
$result=(new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', $fql))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray()
```

e ele me gera o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#12) fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher'

Li que realmente este tipo de comando ja esta ultrapassado, mas nao consegui achar nada de como substituí-lo.

Como fica agora nesta nova API 2.x?

---

Eu tenho este codigo que achei.

```
$fql="/fql?q=SELECT uid, name,pic_square, birthday_date FROM user WHERE (substr(birthday_date, 0, 2) = '07') AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by name&access_token=".$_SESSION["token"];
$session = $this->login();
$result=(new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', $fql))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Como eu faria para usa-lo na nova API.

Comment: João, estamos no mesmo barco. Algumas funcionalidades do FQL não possuem contrapartida direta na Graph API (e.g., [veja essa minha questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33174/100)). Infelizmente, com a data de 30 de Abril batendo na porta, ou migramos por bem ou migramos por mal. Recomendo que você dê uma olhada nos [serviços da Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) e tente substituir seus comandos FQL da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Eu preciso na verda listar os aniversariantes do dia para eu poder enviar uma menssagem para ele. Só vi como fazer isto usando o FQL. Você sabe de alguma forma para isto? Obrigado

Comment: Não sei exatamente qual é o seu caso de uso (se quiser poste o seu FQL e o retorno esperado), porém, sei que com a permissão `user_birthday` você pode consultar o aniversário de um usuário com a chamada: `{id_do_usuario}?fields=birthday`. Para mais informações veja: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

Comment: Então o que preciso é desenvolver um site em PHP que acesse o meu facebook e pegue todos os menus amigos que fazem aniversário no dia e envie uma mensagem genérica para eles. Ja consegui listar todos os amigos, agora falta descobrir quais fazem aniversario no dia e como enviar uma mensagem para eles. Se você poder me ajudar agradeco.

Comment: Poste um [mvce](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) mostrando o seu problema. Assim você consegue ajuda mais específica e direcionada.

Comment: Eu tenho este codigo que achei.

$fql="/fql?q=SELECT uid, name,pic_square, birthday_date FROM user WHERE (substr(birthday_date, 0, 2) = '07') AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by name&access_token=".$_SESSION["token"]; $session = $this->login(); $result=(new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', $fql))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

Como eu faria para usa-lo na nova API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode obter o aniversário de amigos com a seguinte consulta:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/friends?fields=friends{id,name,birthday}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

Para tanto você precisa da autorização `user_friends`.

Veja que desde a versão 2.0 da API essa chamada só retornará amigos do usuário que também usem o seu aplicativo.

Infelizmente, até onde vai meu conhecimento, não há nenhuma maneira de filtrar a data de aniversário diretamente da chamada, você vai precisar iterar os elementos da resposta e filtrar datas do lado cliente.

Comment: Anthony fiz conforme você citou e me resultou isto: Array ( [data] => Array ( ) [summary] => stdClass Object ( [total_count] => 124 ) )

Comment: Você pode testar no [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), provavelmente ou você não requisitou a permissão `user_friends` ou não tem nenhum amigo utilizando a aplicação.

Comment: A permissão eu tenho mas os meus amigos não usam esta meu app. Esta aplicação que estou desenvolvendo é somente para mim. Como eu faria para eles usarem?

Comment: Eles teriam que fazer login na página do aplicativo e autorizar as permissões.

Comment: Somente assim? Eu nao tenho como pedir para os contatos fazerem isto. Não existe outro jeito de ver as datas sem eles autorizarem? Imagino que tambem sem este login deles eu não poderei enviar um feed para eles?

Comment: João, infelizmente não. Você pode tentar [taggable_friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/taggable_friends), mas eles não vem com data de aniversário e é impossível obter o `id` verdadeiro do usuário para consultar a data de aniversário. Desde 2013 também não é possível [postar uma mensagem para o timeline de um amigo pela API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/migrations/completed-changes#feb_2013). As opções são usar uma janela de compartilhamento e / ou as APIs para taggear amigos.

Comment: Que chato, achei que poderia automatizar as minhas tarefas diárias no serviço. Pois são muitos facebooks que tenho que entrar e enviar mensagens para os aniversariantes deles todos os dias. Só mais uma coisa Anthoy como eu escrevo numa fã page. Na pagina eu uso o Post me/feed e na fã Page. Obrigadão.

Comment: Pois é, o Facebook restringe uma série de coisas por motivos de segurança (e para evitar spam). Você pode postar para [`/{page-id}/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed)